# Append after input field

Tags: jquery

The plan is to add JSON data after input field, not inside.
Currently I'm using:

```
var $input = $("<input/>"),
$input.attr('type', 'checkbox');
$input.attr('name', 'formats[]');
$input.attr('value', 'bzz');
$input.html(jsonData['title']);

$("#target").append($input);
```

And it generates:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="formats[]" value="bzz">Data shows here</input>
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to accomplish here. Could you please give an explanation for why you're trying to add JSON data inside an input element?

Comment: I'm adding new checkbox to my form after ajax submit with new data.

Comment: Can you show? What is expected output?

Comment: Sorry I'm misleading you all. Basicly I have <label id="target">Here I need generated input field with my data</label>

Answer (score 0):

Use `insert` or `insertAfter`

It inserts every element in the set of matched elements after the target.

Write:

```
$input.insertAfter($("#target"));
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/q8cRp/) here.

Comment: My #target is label for the input field.

Comment: <label id="target" class="checkbox-inline"></label> This is my target label